# Smart Target - Deployer server cannot find trigger types

Tags: tridion, smarttarget

I'm getting the following the error message in my content delivery logging:

```
com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.AmbientDataHelper - can't find defined 
trigger-types in claim store (check if your smarttarget cartridge is up and running)
```

I've checked out my smarttarget_conf.xml and have confirmed the web services are up and running.  The one that is failing (or returns a 404 via  broswer) is the following:

```
<Endpoint>http://servername:8180/fredhopper/config/trigger-types</Endpoint>
```

But having read through the documentation and the forum, i'm under the impression this is correct and that the url doesn't respond to GET requests.

So I'm assuming everything is set up correctly, in my smarttarget_conf.xml, I'm hoping is anyone has some pointers for me to have a look into to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution**

The issue here is that my trigger-types.xml file was not correctly formed on the FAS (Fredhopper server).  I'm giving Jeremy the winning answer below as he spotted my issue behind the scenes.

Thanks Jeremy - I hope anyone reading this up-votes your answer

Comment: To clarify: the endpoint for the trigger-types does work if you put it in a browser. So that was a clue that your trigger-types.xml was malformed :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The port of my local SmartTarget instance is 8180, not 8080. Perhaps this is the same for you?

Comment: thanks jeremy, i've updated my <endpoint> i'd removed a server name and miss typed 8080 (habit!) instead of 8180.